How do I wait 5 candlesticks before going into another trade after my stoploss was hit on the previous trade?
As you can see in the image below, there were multiple trades entered after the first one hit a stoploss, which resulted in further losses. What can I add to my code to prevent this from happening? Is it possible to make it wait 5 candlesticks after my stoploss was hit before entering another trade?

I tried some commands such as ta.barssince, but I'm new to coding and have started last week and so I'm not quite able to get it to work.
This is my current code:
strategy("Bollinger Band and RSI strategy", "BB&RSI", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100,    default_qty_value = 100, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, commission_value = 0.35, commission_type = strategy.commission.cash_per_order)

upperBollingerBand = ta.sma(close, 30) + (2 * ta.stdev(close, 30))
lowerBollingerBand = ta.sma(close, 30) - (2 * ta.stdev(close, 30))
sma = ta.sma(close, 30)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 13)

goLongCondition1 = close < lowerBollingerBand
goLongCondition2 = rsi < 32.5
exitLongCondition1 = close > sma
goShortCondition1 = close > upperBollingerBand
goShortCondition2 = rsi > 67.5
exitShortCondition1 = close < sma
notInTrade = strategy.position_size == 0
inTrade = strategy.position_size < 0 or strategy.position_size > 0
timePeriod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2024, 05, 5, 17, 00, 00) and time <    timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2024, 05, 5, 23, 00, 00)

if(timePeriod and goLongCondition1 and goLongCondition2 and notInTrade)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1)
    stopLoss = close - 2.5
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", 1, stop=stopLoss)
if(exitLongCondition1 and inTrade)
    strategy.close(id="long", qty = 1)

if(timePeriod and goShortCondition1 and goShortCondition2 and notInTrade)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 1)
    stopLoss = close + 2.5
    strategy.exit("exit", "short", 1, stop = stopLoss)
if(exitShortCondition1 and inTrade)
    strategy.close(id="short", qty = 1)

plot(upperBollingerBand, color = color.red)
plot(lowerBollingerBand, color = color.green)
plot(sma, color = color.blue)

